# Why does SetAuthCookie not work but Response.Cookies.Add does?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, forms-authentication

I had this code and it was not working:

```
FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(userId.ToString(), false);
```

The website basically acted like I hadn't run the line of code at all and kept redirecting back to the login page (if the returnUrl was to an Authorized page).

Thankfully I stumbled on this post: http://melick-rajee.blogspot.com/2015/03/formsauthenticationsetauthcookie-not.html where the user had the same issue apparently, but was able to get the following to do the trick:

```
FormsAuthenticationTicket ticket = new FormsAuthenticationTicket(userId.ToString(), false, 60);
string encTicket = FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(ticket);
Response.Cookies.Add(new HttpCookie(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName, encTicket));
```

The only thing I can think of that might not be standard in my website is that it is a sub-application of another website. Not entirely sure how that affects things but I'd really like to understand why the first way didn't work like it always has for me in other applications.